# Find user/item listed in DLP Report

Tags: office-365, information-policy, compliance-center, dlp

I've started doing some testing with our Office 365 Tenant and the DLP policies. I have a couple (PII and Credit Card) running in test mode and when I look at the policy matches report, the Item and Last modified by are encoded (all start with PII:H101 prefix). Is there any way to actually determine what user/item are in violation? I would like to determine if we're getting valid results.

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 DLP policies creation template provide different options to trigger emails to both the owner of the content as well as to the site collection administration with pre-defined or customized email content.

Once you configure those settings, you will be receiving emails with direct links to the documents or list items where the rule is matched.

Comment: True, but it doesn't help if I'm trying to see it from the macro level. I did send an email to a contact at Microsoft and it appears that I should be seeing the user and document path/name instead of the encoded placeholder. If I get a resolution from him, I'll post it on this thread.